# Why does an unclicked RadioButton click event happen before the program closes?

Tags: delphi, radio-button, mouseclick-event, formclosing

I have a legacy Delphi 6 program that inexplicably receives a click event.  The code has been reduced to the following minimal example for a single form with two RadioButtons:

```
procedure TForm1.RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
showmessage('rb 1 clicked');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
RadioButton2.Checked := TRUE;
showmessage('close query');
end;
```

To demonstrate the problem:

- run the program
- click RadioButton2
- click RadioButton1, which executes `showmessage('rb 1 clicked')`
- close the form

`FormCloseQuery()` will turn on RadioButton2 and executes `showmessage('close query')`, but then `RadioButton1Click()` also executes again!  **Why?**

(The original program was doing various things when the RadioButtons were used, including making sure to do RadioButton2 stuff before exiting by setting `.Checked := TRUE`, but all of that has been removed for the demonstration above.)

The sample code can be created just by creating a new Program1 application, dropping RadioButton1 and RadioButton2 on Form1, and creating the two event handlers above.  RadioButton1 doesn't even need to start out with the Checked property TRUE.

**UPDATE:** Inserting `RadioButton2.SetFocus` after `RadioButton2.Checked := TRUE` prevents the spurious click event.  I'm guessing there's a VCL bug which incorrectly generates an event when focus returns to RadioButton1 after `showmessage('close query')`.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this behaviour in Delphi 10.3. Anyhow, are you sure it is really related to closing the form, and not `RadioButton2.Checked := True` in general? That code is expected to trigger `RadioButton2`'s `OnClick` event (but not that of `RadioButton1`),

Comment: I tried this on my Windows 95 machine with Delphi 4, and I am indeed able to reproduce the behaviour. The first radio button is indeed checked after the `close query` message box has been shown.

Comment: Here is a more simplified test case for you. Put two radios and a button on a form. Button click handler is this: `RadioButton2.Checked := True;` `RadioButton1.SetFocus;` Click the button, you'll notice radio 2 is not checked.

Comment: Not a bug, see the dupe.